# Strange result of numpy polyfit

Tags: python, numpy

I've got strange (from my point of view) result from numpy `polyfit`. My code:

```
import numpy as np
data=np.array([2482.9, 2483.0, 2485.9, 2486.0, 2486.4, 2485.1, 2485.4, 2484.9, 2484.8, 2484.8, 2484.8, 2484.0, 2484.1, 2484.1, 2484.1])
wr = range(len(data))
poly  = np.polyfit(wr , data, deg = 2)
wp  = np.poly1d(poly)
el = 2484.1
res = wp(el)
print(res)
#result -225256.888955
```

Is this a bug?

Comment: What do you get, and what do you expect?

Comment: Did you plot the data? Is a polynom of 2 deg applicable?

Comment: I plotted my data in LibreOffice. Polynom 2 deg is ok. What I got you can see in the code above: 
`#result -225256.888955`

Comment: You're fitting data on an x range of 0-14 which doesn't really look quadratic with a quadratic.  You get one which is concave down, and then you ask for the value at x = ~2500, far outside your range.  What's surprising here?

Comment: You are putting in an x axis value `el` far out of the fit range.

Comment: It looks like you are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DSM has already said - it doesn't look like a quadratic polynom.

We can try to fit it with a higher degree though:

```
import numpy.polynomial.polynomial as poly
x = wr; y = data

coefs = poly.polyfit(x, y, 4)
ffit = poly.Polynomial(coefs)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(x, ffit(x))
plt.legend(['y(x)','ffit(x)'])
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Yes, just confused x with y. Today is not my day :) Too tired to notice that mistake.

Comment: @Prokhozhii, yeah, get some rest ;-)